# File not being written fully using jsch through rest api

Tags: java, rest, file, jsch

I am trying to download a file using jsch through rest api. I am trying to read a file in unix box and write it to a file and download the file. The contents of the file are not written fully when i use the below code. I am trying to read a big file and the file is not being read fully.

```
 @GET
    @Path("/pdf")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
     public Response readFile() {


        StreamingOutput  fileStream =  new StreamingOutput() 
                    {
                        @Override
                        public void write(java.io.OutputStream output) throws IOException, WebApplicationException 
                        { Session session=null;
                         JSch jsch=new JSch();
                            try {

                        session = jsch.getSession("username", "ipAddress", 22);
                            session.setPassword("password");;
                            session.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
                        session.connect();
                            final ChannelExec channel = (ChannelExec) session.openChannel("exec");
                            channel.setCommand("cd /path/; cat filename");
                            channel.setInputStream(null);
                            channel.setErrStream(System.err);
                            final InputStream input = channel.getInputStream();
                            InputStream error = channel.getErrStream();
                            channel.connect();
                            Thread.sleep(30000);
                            byte[] tmp = new byte[100000];
                            while (true) {
                                if (input.available() > 0) {
                                    int i = input.read(tmp, 0, 100000);
                                        if (i < 0)
                                        break;
                                    final StringBuilder temp = new StringBuilder();
                                     temp.append((new String(tmp, 0, i)));                                  

                                    File file=new File("D://mylog.log");
                                    FileOutputStream oS = new FileOutputStream(new File("D://mylog.log"));
                                    oS.write(temp.toString().getBytes());
                                    java.nio.file.Path path = Paths.get("D://mylog.log");                               
                                byte[] data = Files.readAllBytes(path);
                                output.write(data);
                                output.flush();
                                break;
                                }

                            }}
                            catch (Exception e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();

                            } finally {

                            }
                        }
                    };

                    return Response
                            .ok(fileStream, MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
                            .header("content-disposition","attachment; filename = myfile.log")
                            .build();


    }
```

Comment: you should be looping on `read`  *This method blocks until input data is available, end of file is detected, or an exception is thrown.*  read about [available](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#available())

Comment: So what happens, when the file is not "read fully"? Do you get any error? + Is it anyhow related to the REST at all? Did you try the same code in a simple console application?

Comment: i do not get any error, the half written file is downloaded. tried with the simple console application as well and i face the same issue.